# Why is my data filter function returning empty?

Tags: vue.js

When I hit the button `messageIncompleted` it works, but when I click the `messageCompleted` button the data disappears. Can you help me to solve this problem?

```
messageIncompleted() {
    this.messages = this.messages.filter(messages => ! messages.completed );
    this.disabledIncomplete = true;
},
messageCompleted() {
    this.messages = this.messages.filter(messages => messages.completed );
    this.disabledComplete = true;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: doers messages contain any items where completed = false ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `messageIncompleted`, the `this.messages` array is updated with items which have `messages.completed = false`. When you click on `messageCompleted`, the `messages` array won't have any items with `messages.completed = true`.

To fix this, you can create another property called `filteredMessages` to store and display the messages based on criteria. By default, you can set it to `this.messages`. This way, `messages` array won't be directly mutated.

```
messageIncompleted() {
    this.filteredMessages = this.messages.filter(messages => !messages.completed);
    this.disabledIncomplete = true;
},
messageCompleted() {
    this.filteredMessages = this.messages.filter(messages => messages.completed);
    this.disabledComplete = true;
}
```